# tex4ebook OEBPS/content.opf is not a file and OEBPS/book_e.ncx" is not a file

Tags: tex4ebook

After a disk crash and a reinstall of the most recent copy of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I have new messages popping up during a tex4ebook run.

The command `tex4ebook -f epub3 book_e.tex` produces:

```
 [STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion started
 [STATUS]  tex4ebook: Input file: book_e.tex
 [WARNING] tocid: char-def module not found
 [WARNING] tocid: cannot fix section id's
 HTML Tidy for Linux version 5.6.0
 Document: "book_e-epub3/OEBPS/book_e.ncx" is not a file!

 Document: "book_e-epub3/OEBPS/content.opf" is not a file!
 [STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion finished
```

Sigil shows:

[image: shows the above two files as being present.]

The example that produced the above is:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tex4ebook}
    \begin{document} 
    hello there
    \end{document}
```

The .epub can be viewed normally.

Thank you Michal.

Here is the requested log. I could not insert it as a comment, too long...

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex 2022.5.27)  1 JUN 2022 08:06
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCo
de"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.
{\AddToHook{class/before}{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}\RequirePackage{tex4e
book}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expan
dafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4h
t,}@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode xhtml,book
_e.tex,charset=utf-8,charset=utf-8,epub,uni-html4.a.b.c.\input "\detokenize{epu
b}"
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...,uni-html4.a.b.c.\input "\detokenize{epub}"
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
18 strings out of 480248
386 string characters out of 5896177
283955 words of memory out of 5000000
18063 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
12i,0n,19p,589b,10s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.

---

tex4ebook -m draft -a debug -f epub3 book_e.tex

Log file:

### This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex 2022.5.27)  1 JUN 2022 15:45
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCo
de"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.
{\AddToHook{class/before}{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}\RequirePackage{tex4e
book}\Configure{ext}{xhtml}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\doc
umentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####
1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeat
other\HCode xhtml,,charset=utf-8,charset=utf-8,epub3,html5,uni-html4.a.b.c.\inp
ut "\detokenize{book_e.tex}"
(./book_e.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty
version 2021-09-14-14:11
Package: tex4ht

### --- Note --- for _ at preamble, use the command line option `early_'

---

### --- Note --- for ^ at preamble, use the command line option `early^'

\tmp:toks=\toks16
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/usepackage.4ht
version 2022-01-11-14:12
)
(/home/steve/texmf/tex/latex/tex4ebook/tex4ebook.sty
Package: tex4ebook 2016/03/31 version 0.1d

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count185
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/graphics-hooks.4ht
version 2020-10-17-13:53
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 107.

### (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen138
\Gin@req@width=\dimen139
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count186
\c@section=\count187
\c@subsection=\count188
\c@subsubsection=\count189
\c@paragraph=\count190
\c@subparagraph=\count191
\c@figure=\count192
\c@table=\count193
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.4ht
version 2021-06-20-15:33

### --- Note --- for additional information, use the command line option `info'

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
TeX4ht info is available in the log file
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty
version 2021-09-14-14:11

l.855 --- TeX4ht warning --- nonprimitive \everypar ---
--- needs --- tex4ht book_e ---
\tmp:cnt=\count194
\openout15 = `book_e.tmp'.

(./book_e.tmp)
\tmp:dim=\skip49
(./book_e.xref)
:refout=\write3
\openout3 = `book_e.xref'.

### (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2022-02-03-14:35

### --- Note --- to remove the  processing instruction use the c
ommand line option `no-VERSION'

---

### --- Note --- to remove the DOCTYPE declaration use the command line option `no-
DOCTYPE'

### )
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2021-06-19-14:11
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2021-04-16-13:27
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht
version 2022-01-23-07:51
)

--- Note --- for marking of the base font, use the command line option `fonts+'

---

---

### --- Note --- for non active *, use the command line option `no*'

---

### --- Note --- for _ of catcode 13, use the command line option `_13'

---

### --- Note --- for non active ^, use the command line option `no^'

---

### --- Note --- for ^ of catcode 13, use the command line option `^13'

### (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2022-02-03-14:35

### --- Note --- to ignore CSS font decoration, use the `NoFonts' command line opti
on

---

### --- Note --- for jpg bitmaps of pictures, use the `jpg' command line option. (C haracter bitmaps are controled only by` g' records of tex4ht.env and `-g' switc
hes of tex4ht.c)

---

### --- Note --- for gif bitmaps of pictures, use the `gif' command line option. (C haracter bitmaps are controled only by` g' records of tex4ht.env and `-g' switc
hes of tex4ht.c)

---

### --- Note --- for content and toc in 2 frames, use the command line option `fram
es'

---

### --- Note --- for content, toc, and footnotes in 3 frames, use the command line
option `frames-fn'

---

### --- Note --- for file extension name xht, use the command line option `xht'

### TeX4ht package options: xhtml,charset=utf-8,epub3,html5,uni-html4,html

### --- Note --- To print a timestamp, use the command line option timestamp

---

### --- Note --- to ignore CSS code, use the command line option `-css

---

### --- Note --- for inline CSS code, use the command line option `css-in'

---

--- Note --- for pop ups on mouse over, use the command line option `mouseover'

---

---

### --- Note --- for addressing images in a subdirectory, use the command line opti
on `imgdir:.../'

### )
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2021-06-19-14:11
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2021-04-16-13:27
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht
version 2022-01-23-07:51

### --- Note --- To print a timestamp, use the command line option timestamp

### )
:tokwrite=\toks18
:tokpage=\toks19

### --- Note --- for back links to toc, use the command line option `sections+'

---

--- Note --- for linear crosslinks of pages, use the command line option `next'

---

\openout15 = `book_e.4ct'.

:tocout=\write4
\openout4 = `book_e.4tc'.

### (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2022-02-03-14:35
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2021-06-19-14:11
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2021-04-16-13:27
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht
version 2022-01-23-07:51
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/latex.4ht
version 2022-02-01-14:27
LaTeX Info: Redefining _ on input line 173.
LaTeX Info: Redefining , on input line 792.
LaTeX Info: Redefining ; on input line 793.
LaTeX Info: Redefining ! on input line 794.
LaTeX Info: Redefining : on input line 795.
LaTeX Info: Redefining > on input line 796.

### --- Note --- for links into captions, instead of float heads, use the command l
ine option `refcaption'

### (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2022-02-03-14:35
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2021-06-19-14:11
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2021-04-16-13:27
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht
version 2022-01-23-07:51
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2022-02-03-14:35

### --- Note --- For mini tocs immediately aftter the header use the command line o
ption `minitoc<'

---

### --- Note --- for enumerated list elements with valued data, use the command lin
e option `enumerate+'

---

### --- Note --- for enumerated list elements li's with value attributes, use the c
ommand line option `enumerate-'

---

### --- Note --- for CSS2 code, use the command line option `css2'

---

### --- Note --- for pictorial tabular, use the command line option `pic-tabular'

---

### --- Note --- for bitmap fbox'es, use the command line option `pic-fbox'

---

--- Note --- for bitmap framebox'es, use the command line option `pic-framebox'

---

---

### --- Note --- for inline footnotes use command line option `fn-in'

---

### --- Note --- for tracing of latex font commands, use the command line option `f
onts'

---

### --- Note --- for width specifications of tabular p entries, use the `p-width' c
ommand line option or a configuration similar to \Configure{HColWidth}{\HCode{
style="width:\HColWidth"}}

### )
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2021-06-19-14:11
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2021-04-16-13:27

--- Note --- for pictorial eqnarray, use the command line option `pic-eqnarray'

---

---

### --- Note --- for pictorial array, use the command line option `pic-array'

---

### --- Note --- for pictorial $...$ environments, use the command line option `pic
-m' (not recommended!!)

---

### --- Note --- for pictorial $...$ and $$...$$ environments with latex alt, use t
he command line option `pic-m+' (not safe!!)

---

### --- Note --- for pictorial array, use the command line option `pic-array'

)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht
version 2022-01-23-07:51
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/fontmath.4ht
version 2018-11-06-15:55

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2022-02-03-14:35
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2021-06-19-14:11
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2021-04-16-13:27
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht
version 2022-01-23-07:51
))
(/home/steve/texmf/tex/latex/tex4ebook/tex4ebook.4ht
\opf:htmlid=\count195
\navpoint=\count196

(/home/steve/texmf/tex/latex/tex4ebook/tex4ebook-epub3.4ht
\footnotebox=\box50
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/graphicx.4ht
version 2022-01-12-13:53

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2022-02-03-14:35
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2021-06-19-14:11
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2021-04-16-13:27
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht
version 2022-01-23-07:51
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/graphics.4ht
version 2021-08-12-13:49

### (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2022-02-03-14:35

### --- Note --- if included graphics are of degraded quality, try the command line
options `graphics-num' or` graphics-'. The `num' should provide the density of
pixels in the bitmaps (e.g., 110).

---

### --- Note --- for key dimensions try the option `Gin-dim'; for key dimensions wh en bounding box is unavailable try` Gin-dim+'; neither is recommended

)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2021-06-19-14:11
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2021-04-16-13:27
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht
version 2022-01-23-07:51
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/dvips.4ht
version 2009-05-21-09:32

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2022-02-03-14:35
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2021-06-19-14:11
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2021-04-16-13:27
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht
version 2022-01-23-07:51
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/article.4ht
version 2021-05-16-09:21

### (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2022-02-03-14:35

### --- Note --- for automatic sectioning pagination, use the command line option `1',`2', `3', '4', '5', '6', or '7'

---

### --- Note --- for files named derived from section titles, use the command line
option `sec-filename'

---

### --- Note --- for i-columns index, use the command line option `index=i' (e.g.,
index=2)

)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2021-06-19-14:11
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2021-04-16-13:27
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht
version 2022-01-23-07:51
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2022-02-03-14:35
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2021-06-19-14:11
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2021-04-16-13:27
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht
version 2022-01-23-07:51
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2022-01-12 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count197
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box52
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box53
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count198
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count199
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count266
)
(./book_e.aux)
\openout1 = `book_e.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
--- file book_e.css ---
(./book_e.4ct) [1

] (./book_e.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
5490 strings out of 480248
72597 string characters out of 5896177
486490 words of memory out of 5000000
23341 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
469559 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
89i,5n,113p,911b,465s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on book_e.dvi (1 page, 12052 bytes).

---

tex4ebook -m draft -a debug -f epub3 book_e.tex - Terminal output shows:

### [INFO]    mkutils:  xhtml,charset=utf-8,epub3,html5,uni-html4,html
[INFO]    mkutils: executing: tex4ht  -cmozhtf -utf8 -cmozhtf -utf8 "book_e.dvi"

tex4ht.c (2018-07-03-10:36 kpathsea)
tex4ht -cmozhtf
-utf8
-cmozhtf
-utf8
book_e.dvi
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/mozilla/charset/unicode.4hf)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/lm/lm-rep-cmrm/cmr.htf)
Searching `lm-rep-cmrm.htf' for` cmr10.htf'
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/lm/lm-rep-cmrm.htf)
[1 file book_e.xhtml
file book_e.css
file book_e.tmp
file book_e.ncx
file content.opf
file content-part2.opf
]
Execute script `book_e.lg'

### [INFO]    make4ht-lib: executing: t4ht  "book_e.dvi"

t4ht.c (2018-07-04-14:25 kpathsea)
t4ht book_e.dvi
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env)
Entering book_e.lg
Entering book_e.css
Entering book_e.tmp

[INFO]    mkutils: Parse LG
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: book_e.xhtml
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: book_e.tmp
[INFO]    exec_epub3: write container
[INFO]    mkutils: Copy: cp "book_e.xhtml" "book_e-epub3/OEBPS"
[INFO]    mkutils: Copy: cp "book_e.css" "book_e-epub3/OEBPS"
[INFO]    exec_epub: Mimetype for tmp is not registered
[INFO]    mkutils: Copy: cp "book_e.ncx" "book_e-epub3/OEBPS"
[INFO]    exec_epub: Mimetype for opf is not registered
[INFO]    exec_epub: Mimetype for opf is not registered
[INFO]    mkutils: Copy: cp "content.opf" "book_e-epub3/OEBPS"
[INFO]    exec_epub3: no TOC, using a generic one
[INFO]    exec_epub3: Main file name: book_e.xhtml
HTML Tidy for Linux version 5.6.0
Document: "book_e-epub3/OEBPS/book_e.ncx" is not a file!

[INFO]    exec_epub: Tidy ncx 0
Document: "book_e-epub3/OEBPS/content.opf" is not a file!

[INFO]    exec_epub: Tidy opf 0
[INFO]    exec_epub: Pack mimetype 0
[INFO]    exec_epub: Pack metadir 0
[INFO]    exec_epub: Pack outputdir 0
[INFO]    exec_epub: Copy generated epub
[INFO]    mkutils: Copy: cp "book_e-epub3/book_e.epub" "book_e.epub"
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion finished

Comment: could you run tex4ebook with the `-a debug` option and post the log file here?

Comment: Michal, I have edited the post to include the output of the -a run.  Thanks

Comment: ah, this log doesn't look good, the compilation failed. please try `tex4ebook -m draft -a debug -f epub3 book_e.tex`, and insert the full terminal output, not just the log file. I am mostly interested in the end of the compilation, as it should include more information why tidy failed

Comment: Both log and terminal output added....

Comment: thanks! it seems that this can be an issue with file permissions, which seems weird: https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues/681 Anyway, `tidy` is not really necessary for the processing of the NCX and OPF files, it just makes nicer formatting. But you should get valid Epub file even without Tidy.